# Email a existing pdf file with password protection

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, password-protection

I have created a pdf using `itextsharp`. The requirement is that while sending the PDF as attachment in an email and it should be password protected.

I know that we can make a pdf password protected while creating it using `itextsharp`.

Is there any way to make an existing pdf password protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PdfReader` in combination with `PdfStamper` and the `setEncryption()` method.

In Java, see `encryptPdf()` in this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=219

In C#, see `EncryptPdf()` in this example: http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter12&ex=EncryptionPdf

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I checked the examples and those are helpful.